# Tabula: PIP Installer says "Successful Download", but unable to import

Tags: python, import, tabula

I have downloaded, using pip, tabula, a library used to read pdf files:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

However, when I try to import tabula using:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula'
```

I am running this on Spyder on anaconda3 console. What is wrong?

EDIT 1:

When I run the program on Terminal, the error does not appear. However, I am lazy and don't want to switch between Spyder and Terminal.

EDIT 2:

I am using Mac on HighSierraOS.

EDIT 3:

I have "abandoned" tabula and am now using PyPDF2. I prefer PyPDF 2 because it gets annoying when tabula opens Java everytime I read a pdf file. PyPDF2 seems to be quicker. (not sponsored by PyPDF2)

Comment: make sure your current file name is not "Tabula"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabula` requires `python 3.5+`. So make sure you are running with python 3.

Run `python --version`on your terminal, to check your python version

Answer (score 1):

With `which pip` you can check in which environment `tabula-py` is installed.
Note that when you have different versions of python and/or anaconda you have to pay attention since packages may be installed in the wrong place.

As it works with python but not within anaconda, a solution is to install the library inside anaconda with `/a/b/.../anaconda/bin/pip install tabula-py` according to your path.

Comment: That more looks like an error with the filename (probably, named "Tabula")